# Segmentation fault when using Tesserocr in Docker

Tags: python, docker, segmentation-fault, tesseract

I'm using a Docker container with Ubuntu 14.04 image and I'm trying to run tesseract-ocr in it, using the python wrapper tesserocr.

The version details are as follows:

```
tesseract 4.00.00alpha
 leptonica-1.74.4
  libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.3.0) : libpng 1.2.50 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8

 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

The code that I'm using is:

```
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI
from PIL import Image

x = Image.open('image.jpg')

with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    api.SetImage(x)
    api.Recognize()
    ri=api.GetIterator()
    print api.GetUTF8Text()
```

The memory details inside the docker are(using `free -m`) :

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         12012      10280       1731          1        420       8738
-/+ buffers/cache:       1121      10890
Swap:        12284         64      12220
```

I'm getting the following error when I run the code:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And the memory details are almost the same when I run it in my machine (no docker container) and it runs fine for the same image.

What could be causing this issue and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub Issue #55](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/55) on the [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr) project on seems to be similar to your problem. Have you tried the fix suggested here?

Comment: What suggestions mentioned here did you try exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. To solve it, first I ran Docker container with tesserocr installed. Inside the container, I ran python and tried this:

```
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI
```

... and got this error:

```
!strcmp(locale, "C"):Error:Assert failed:in file baseapi.cpp
```

Which lead me [here](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/165).

Suggested [answer](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/165#issuecomment-443695405):

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')
import tesserocr
```

fixed the error.